# Vue 2 + Laravel 6 error (Access-Control-Allow-Origin)

Tags: laravel, csv, vue.js, cors

I was creating my first project between Vue 2 and Laravel 6, I could read information from the API through GET, but I was trying to send a CSV file from the frontend **http://localhost/8080** to the backend **http://127.0.0.1:8000**, but I get the following message
[Here I get a cors error, which I have reported and I have seen that it is because they are from different servers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uil7M.png)

My request from Vue is the following:

```
axios
    .post("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/import", this.file, {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
      },
    })
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log(response);
      console.log("SUCCESS!!");
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
```

The route of my Laravel has the following line

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'cors'], function () {
Route::apiResource("naves", "StarwarsController");
Route::post('import', 'StarwarsController@import');});
```

In the controller I have the following code

```
public function import(Request $request)
{
    return var_dump($request);
    $request->file('images');}
```

And about CORS I have the following information
Cors.php

```
class Cors
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        return $next($request)
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS')
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization');
    }
}
```

and Kernel.php

```
protected $middleware = [
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class
    ];
protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'password.confirm' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\RequirePassword::class,
        'signed' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
        'cors' => \App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class,
    ];
```

If you could help me I would appreciate it a lot!

Solution:

```php
$origin = (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'] : '*';
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ' . $origin);
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST');
        header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 1000');
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
        header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');

        if ($this->input->server('REQUEST_METHOD') == 'OPTIONS') {
            header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: authorization, content-type');
            echo json_encode(array());
            exit;
        }
```

Comment: try/see if moving the cors middleware to the top works

Comment: try to add it in top of your route file 
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:8080');

Comment: @MTakumi Thanks for your answer, but it still doesn't work for me with your contributions

Comment: @user3532758 I already solved it, sorry, the stack overflow does not notify me, I do not know how to publish the result because it tells me that I lack reputation. The solution if it is with Allow-Origin